# Why does mmHg persist in organic chemistry?

Tags: terminology, units

In most areas of chemistry, standard units are adopted - we never would think to use ounces (even American chemists resist) BUT even in modern journals or textbooks, we commonly still see the unit `mmHg` used. Why is this the case and why have people not moved to adopt SI units in this situation?

To give an example, consider the "Purification of Laboratory Chemicals" book that is often referenced here. Many distillations are given using pressures in mmHg.

Comment: In comparison with `inHg` and `psi`, `mmHg` looks pretty decent. Also, habits and arguably convenience when interpreting information from the resources as dusty as the first Merck's Index.

Comment: Predominantly habit, I suppose.  Most people of a certain age remember ACTUAL manometers that used millimetres of mercury.

Comment: Actual millimeters of actual mercury, I would stress. I remember them myself, and I'm not that old. Once in a while they would break and spill mercury all around, which was a peculiar kind of fun.

Comment: Unfortunately the same reason why the modern HPLC I use registers pressure in Megapascals on the hardware (which is fine that is SI) and psi on the software (pisses me off:). Convention, and stubbornness.

Comment: I just graduated from grad school last year and I exclusively used Schlenk lines with actual mercury bubblers with (metric) yard sticks attached for distillations. It was very convenient to measure the pressure in mmHg.

Comment: Possibly it's academia.  No modern chemist in Industry would use that unit. I saw inchHg from a CMO the other week and it rang alarm bells. It meant they were using an analogue guage and hence, an old possibly uncalibrated one.